# FB social Login PHP - Why People take it as so difficult?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I was implementing `FB social` login in website based on PHP. I checked FB website and found it easy to implement. Below is the approach i have followed and i am not sure that i have any **security issues here**.

> I have used Facebook JS SDK approach.

and is as follows:

```
var appID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : appID, // App ID
  channelUrl : '',
  status     : true,
  cookie     : true,
  xfbml      : true, 
}); 
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // connected
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,permissions', function(response) {
        //alert('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
}else{

}
});
};

function login() {
  if( navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS') ){ 
  }
  else{
  FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
          replace_login();
      } else {
          // cancelled
          alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
      }
  },{scope: 'email,public_profile,user_friends'});
}
}

function replace_login(){
   FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email', function(response) {
       $.ajax({
          url: "s-account",
          type: 'POST',
          data: response,
          dataType: 'json',
          beforeSend: function(){
              $("#signin_fb").button('loading');
          },
          success: function(data) {
             $("#signin_fb").button('reset');
             window.location.reload();
          },
          error: function(){
              $("#signin_fb").button('reset');
          }
       });
   });
}
```

And in PHP at server side, i am storing user detail like `social_id, name and email` in database through ajax call and if DB operation is successful then i am setting `Session Variable` in my website with `username and email` and user is logged in successfully.

For logout, i am using my own logout function to destroy Website user session and user is successfully logged out.

> Now, where is the security risk? because if user is logged out and then try to login again JS SDK shall get a new Access Token through new response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This whole authentication process boils down to the ajax call to `s-account`. You're sending *name* and *email* from *FB.api()* to your back end application in a POST request and as you didn't mention, I presume you're not verifying the access token with these details on the server side and you're simply making a session based on these details.

**The security issue**

Now, the security issue is that you're using a client side authentication on the server side. A user can simply generate a POST request to `s-account` with a fake response like Facebook with any *username* and *email* address and your PHP application will authenticate the user and make a valid session without verifying if the details are coming from a legit source. Your authentication is completely broken at this stage because a malicious user can login with any account by generating a simple POST request to `s-account` with any *email* and *username*.

**How to fix**

Facebook provides an end-point in the graph API which validates an access token and returns the details of the user associated with this access token. From the [Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/debug_token):

> This endpoint returns metadata about a given access token. This
>   includes data such as the user for which the token was issued, whether
>   the token is still valid, when it expires, and what permissions the
>   app has for the given user.

The Fb.Login() will generate the access token as `response.authResponse.accessToken` and userId as `response.authResponse.userID`. You need to send this `accessToken` & `userID` along with the other user details in your ajax call to `s-account` and then use the following API end-point to validate if the details are legit.

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/debug_token?input_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_AJAX_CALL&access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

If the the access token is valid, you'll get the following response with the userID for which this token was issued.

```
{
  "data": {
    "app_id": "YOUR_APP_ID",
    "application": "YOUR_APP_NAME",
    "expires_at": 1462777200,
    "is_valid": true,
    "scopes": [
      "email",
      "manage_pages",
      "pages_messaging",
      "pages_messaging_phone_number",
      "public_profile"
    ],
    "user_id": "THE_USER_ID_ASSOCIATED_WITH_THE_TOKEN"
  }
}
```

Now you can compare this `userID` with the userID you received in the ajax call and check if the details are legit.

**How to get your APP_ACCESS_TOKEN**

To debug the user access token using the debug_token API, you need to generate your APP access token on the server side using the following API end-point.

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials"
```

This will return your app access token in response.

```
{
  "access_token": "YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE",
  "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

Comment: Brilliant.. I have figured out this POST call issue with fake data yesterday and kinda fixed it.. but your explanation gives more secure solution. Where to place this `curl -X GET` and what is `YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN`. Is it APP ID?

Comment: No,  app access token is not the appId. Read the final section "How to get your APP_ACCESS_TOKEN".
  
"curl -X GET" represents an HTTP request to the API. You can use PHPs CURL (http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) to make this HTTP request on the server side.

Comment: At first after POST `How to get your APP_ACCESS_TOKEN` need to executed.. right?

Comment: using FB PHP SDK can also help here.. right? to get all these details?

Comment: Yes .. But I won't recommend using a whole SDK for only 2 - 3 HTTP requests. If you're planning to expand the functionality later then you should. And Yes, `APP_ACCESS_TOKEN` should be the first thing you should do after the ajax call on the server side.

Comment: what shall be the value of grant_type=client_credentials

Comment: This string will be as it is .. grant_type=client_credentials .. No value here ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111375/discussion-between-gags-and-mukarram-khalid).